# File server audit for multiple file types

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2

So, here's the deal...one of our clients never put any sort of restrictions on their file servers in regards to what type of files their users could put in their network drives. So, users being users, they put everything on them, including movies, songs, jpg's, etc etc etc.

While they're not planning on putting any restrictions in place right now (something I've fought for multiple times, but hey, I can only push so far), I have to get together a list of the various file types on the servers, and a list containing at least a majority of the file locations so we can try to clean up what we can before they migrate their data to a combination of OneDrive and a hosting solution later this year/early next year. This would include for .pst files, .ost files, .jpg, .avi, .mpg, .mp4, and at least potentially others.

Does anyone have any recommendations for a utility or PowerShell script to find and create a list of any folders containing files of specific file types, along with the size of the folder? I've been using WinDirStat for a lot of this stuff, but without being able to create a report of any sort, it's usefulness for this task is fairly limited, unless if I want to spend days going through it for each of the four file servers. I've been looking around online, but I haven't found anything so far.

Comment: `one of our clients never put any sort of restrictions on their file servers in regards to what type of files their users could put in their network drives` - Well that's really none of your business. What they decide to save on their file server is their business. If they've hired you to implement some restrictions then that's one thing, if they haven't then my advice would be to stick to the task that they actually hired you for.

Comment: Yes...and now they want us to try to identify any files that shouldn't be there prior to the migration to hosting/OneDrive. So please, lose the uninformed attitude.

Comment: There's no attitude here. If they've hired you to remove and restrict certain file types then fine, that's perfectly acceptable. When an IT professional states they they've "fought" with a client for years to get something done (that the IT professional brings their own bias into), then I have a bit of a problem with that attitude. You can advise and guide them. You can make recommendations based on your experience, opinion and best practice but it's not your place to impose your will on the clients, which is how I took your comment about fighting the client on the issue. No offense intended.

Comment: If you honestly think I had been fighting with them, then you're insane... There have been nearly constant issues with their DFS environment and with their storage infrastructure, due almost entirely to their practice of allowing anything and everything to be stored on the file servers. Our "manager" at the client is aware of this, and agrees, he's just (understandably) wary about getting into a possible political firestorm with the various site managers. But he also knows it'll need to be done eventually, preferably before the migration when they'll start paying monthly for storage.

Comment: @SteveFreeman The problem, really, is that DFS-R is just terrible.  I'll bet that the issues you're having are a result of using it in an unsupported and non-recommended fashion that it doesn't handle well, which to be fair, is justifiable, since the only supported, recommended DFS-R implementations are basically worthless.  I've been through this dance at four employers and more consulting gigs than I can count, and really, the only thing you should be doing with DFS-R is turning it off.  Eliminating user media files is not going to solve your problem, because DFS-R chokes on everything.

Comment: In your question, you wrote "I fought for years". In a comment, you wrote "If you honestly think I had been fighting with them, then you're insane". Please take a moment to consider how wording your question and comments differently might improve your chances of getting people to help you in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[File Server Resource Manager (FSRM) Reports](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731206(v=ws.10).aspx).

> File Server Resource Manager can generate reports that will help you understand file use on the storage server. You can use the storage reports to monitor disk usage patterns (**by file type** or user), identify duplicate files and dormant files, track quota usage, and audit file screening.

Comment: Thanks, I'm taking a look at this right now. From a quick view, it looks like it MAY hopefully give me what I need.